# Bypass Login Screen in Drupal 7 through a special URL

Tags: authentication, drupal-7, autologin

I am into a strange fix with my site.

Firstly, my site is password protected. So, when I visit, http://www.mysite.com it is greeted with a nice shiny login page. User puts in the credentials and goes in.

Now, I am hoping that for some special people, they don't have to login. For that I need to have some specific URL, say, http://www.mysite.com/bypass which takes me to the site without any login page.

Is it possible?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, but I wouldn't recommend it. A good option would be to just tell those special people to have their browser save the password.

To actually implement what you want - to log in without login credentials you'd have to do something like what "[drush user-login](http://drush.ws/#user-login)" does. It creates a one-time link that allows anyone to become "logged in". It's the same functionality as the password reset link. You could probably detect the (type of) link and re-route it to the http://www.mysite.com/bypass address.

In the end it's best just not to do it.

Comment: I am sorry I am unable to do it through this. Is it possible for you to give a specific example? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a specific example, sorry. As far as I know nobody has done it like this before. Let me say it again - it's a bad idea in any case.